# Custom back button throws exception in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to implement a custom back button in iOS.

This is the code for the button inside viewDidLoad method:

```
let customFont = UIFont(name: "ChalkDuster", size: 17.0)
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: customFont!], forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "<<<", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: navigationController, action: "transition:")
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
```

Then the function transition() is as follows:

```
func transition() {
        print ("estoy aqui")
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

    }
```

But I am getting an exception after touching the button:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController
>   transition:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9f84008a00'

I don't know how to solve the exception.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove semicolon at the end of the Selector. `transition:` to `transition`.
Also change target `navigationController` to `self`.

Comment: Thank you, but already tested as you propose, I have tried "transition:" "transition()" and "transition" with the same result.

Comment: Same result changing navigationController to self.navigationController

Comment: No no, just self! not self.navigationController.

Comment: It should be working if you set target to 'self' and action to 'transition'

Comment: It works, sorry....you are right, changing ("transition:") to ("transition") and target: navigationController to self works...